# Replace a specific cell value based on what another cell starts with

Tags: excel, vba

I have spreadsheets with names in the form `Last, First Name` listed in Column A, then in column S is the name of a person assigned to that original individual. I need to search column S for two particular names, then based on what the last name begins with in column A, change the entry in column S to something different.

Example, before any change is made:

[image]

- In column S, if the entry is Bert, check column A.
- If that value begins with A-K, replace Bert with Grover
- if it starts with L-Z, replace it with Elmo.
- Also, for column S, find and replace for Ernie based on A-K = Elmo and L-Z = Grover.
- Leave other entries in column S as they are.
- FINALLY, if in column S the value is Grover, change the cell next to it in column T to Example1
- and if it is Elmo change the cell next to in in column T to Example2
- Otherwise don't change anything in column T

Desired result after code has run (highlighting added just to show what was changed - not a requirement):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to change the values in column S, you 'd need a macro to do so.
Something like this?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim str As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Blad1")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 1))

For Each cell In rng
    If Asc(Left(cell.Value, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(Left(cell.Value, 1)) < 76 Then
        str = "Grover"
    ElseIf Asc(Left(cell.Value, 1)) >= 76 And Asc(Left(cell.Value, 1)) < 91 Then
        str = "Elmo"
    End If

    If ws.Cells(cell.Row, 19).Value = "Bert" Then
        ws.Cells(cell.Row, 19).Value = str
    End If
    If ws.Cells(cell.Row, 19).Value = "Grover" Then
        ws.Cells(cell.Row, 20).Value = "Example1"
    ElseIf ws.Cells(cell.Row, 19).Value = "Elmo" Then
        ws.Cells(cell.Row, 20).Value = "Example2"
    End If

Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Lambik

I ended up copying the "For Each cell In rng" part over again to replace for Ernie too. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use VBA for this, you can easily accomplish this with a formula, just like this one:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1;1)="a";"Yes";"No")
```

This formula verifies if cell `A1` starts with one small letter `"a"` (the number `1` in the `LEFT()` worksheet function means the number of characters to take). If yes, it puts `"Yes"`, else it puts `"No"`.
Dragging such a formula over the whole column `S` might solve your issue.

Comment: I do not believe that's correct, as the question is to look for the range A-K and L-Z and to replace values depending on the result. Your formula only evaluates if the cell value in A1 (and subsequent using drag down) begins with "a".

Comment: I didn't mean to provide with a complete answer, just a starting point which can be used for finding the solution.